# What are the solutions of the equation matrix $W^2 =\alpha W$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ be the set of real and symmetric matrices $m \times m$ and let $\alpha$ be a positive number. What is the set of all solutions, depending of $m$, of the equation 
$$
W^2 = \alpha W
$$
in $\mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ when $m>1$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Since $W$ is real and symmetric, it is diagonalizable (by orthogonal matrices). So the question is what diagonal matrices satisfy the equation. For these, their eigenvalues will have to satisfy $\lambda^2=\alpha\lambda$, so either $\lambda=0$ or $\lambda=\alpha$.

So $W=UDU^T$, with $U$ orthogonal and $D$ diagonal with $D_{jj}\in\{0,\alpha\}$ for all $j$.

Put in a different way, $W$ is symmetric with eigenvalues  only  $0$ and/or $\alpha$

Comment: Note that if $m=\alpha=3$  then $W = \mathbb{1}_m \mathbb{1}_m^T$ is a solution and $\alpha$ as the only eigenvalue. And  $W = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 &1& 1 \\ 1&1&1 \end{array} \right)\left(\begin{array}{ccc} \alpha & 0 & 0 \\ 0 &0& 0 \\ 0&0&0 \end{array} \right)\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 &1& 1 \\ 1&1&1 \end{array} \right)$. However the matrix $U=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 &1& 1 \\ 1&1&1 \end{array} \right)$   is not orthogonal.

Comment: @jaogye: I don't see how that's relevant. Your $W$ is $$W=\begin{bmatrix} 3&3&3\\3&3&3\\3&3&3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1/\sqrt3&0&\sqrt2/\sqrt3\\ 1/\sqrt3&1/\sqrt2&-1/\sqrt6\\1/\sqrt3&-1/\sqrt2&-1/\sqrt6\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}9&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1/\sqrt3&1/\sqrt3&1/\sqrt3\\ 0&1/\sqrt2&-1/\sqrt2\\ \sqrt2/\sqrt3&-1/\sqrt6&-1/\sqrt6\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: @jaogye Your example is contained in the set of solutions described in the answer: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Diagonalize+%7B%7B1,1,1%7D,%7B1,1,1%7D,%7B1,1,1%7D%7D.%7B%7Ba,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,0%7D%7D.%7B%7B1,1,1%7D,%7B1,1,1%7D,%7B1,1,1%7D%7D

Comment: @Surb: yes. Still, note that Wolfram Alpha is diagonalizing by similarity, so its answer is not entirely relevant. That's why I wrote the concrete example (which I could do quickly because I taught diagonalization two weeks ago, otherwise it would have been a small scramble :D )

Comment: I agree that the eigenvalues are 0 or $\alpha$. However it was not clear for me, what the possible values for $U$ were. Your example clarifies me that $U$ can be a matrix whose columns are orthogonal vectors and not necesarly $U$ must be full rank.

Comment: @jaogye: $U$ is a unitary so it is always full rank.

Comment: Dear @Martin Argerami your solution in terms of $U^T D U $ is ok but I expected how to prove or disprove that the unique solutions of $W^2 = \alpha W$ are the diagonal matrices with $W_{ii} \in \{0,\alpha\}$ and constant matrices as $\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{array} \right)$ (Sorry for my lack of accuracy).

Comment: You won't be able to prove that because it's not true. Take any unitary $U$, any $\alpha$, form $D$ with a number of $\alpha$ in the diagonal and the rest zeroes, and then $W=UDU^*$ satisfies $W^2=\alpha W$. To make a silly example if you take $$W=\begin{bmatrix} 15/4&-5\sqrt3/4&0\\ -5\sqrt3/4&5/4&0\\0&0&5\end{bmatrix},$$ then $W^2=5W$.